# Limesurvey get combo values of a question

Tags: api, limesurvey

When I perform an export_responses call to the API, I get the questions and values.

For combo type questions, I get the ID of the selected option, but not the description.
How can I access the descriptions of these values?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter sResponseType in the API allows you to choose if you want to get the Answer Codes or the Answer Texts.

Please see https://api.limesurvey.org/classes/remotecontrol_handle.html#method_export_responses

> Export token response in a survey.
>
> export_responses_by_token(string
>   $sSessionKey, integer $iSurveyID, string $sDocumentType, string
>   $sToken, string $sLanguageCode = null, string $sCompletionStatus =
>   'all', string $sHeadingType = 'code', string $sResponseType = 'short',
>   array $aFields = null) : array|string
>
> ...
>   ...
>
> sResponseType (optional)'short' or 'long' Optional defaults to 'short'

Comment: Thank you Gabriel!!.  You're right. It's working now, also in export_responses function.